# Why does copying a string to a char* with snprintf crash with some strings, and not others?

Tags: c++, arrays, char, printf

I am converting a std::string to a char[] in a c++ dll application to pass through to a C# application.

in my Header i have:

`char m_Text[1000];`

in my cpp function:

```
void createLogEntry(std::string logMessage)
{
    logMessage = "testing testing";
//  logMessage = "testing testing 12121221.121212  ,1  12. .121212. .2 2 21";

    log_mutex.lock();
    snprintf ( m_Text, 100, logMessage.c_str() );

    log_mutex.unlock();

}
```

When I run the shorter string "testing testing", everything is fine. When I run with the other, commented out string, the application crashes. Why is this? And what can I do about it? I have tried using `strcpy(m_Text, logMessage.c_str());`, I have tried a larger array, and i see the same thing.

Comment: Why are you using `snprintf` if you're not using a format string?

Comment: What is `m_Text`?  How big is it?

Comment: I switched to `snprintf ` after reading that `strncpy()` does not always null terminate strings. Is that wrong? m_Text is `char m_Text[1000];`, as above.

Comment: @anti Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Note that `logMessage.c_str()` gives you back a pointer to a `char[]` that you could pass to your C# application. You might not need all this wheel-spinning.

Comment: You should use snprintf ( m_Text, 100, "%s", logMessage.c_str() ); to avoid the application crash.

Comment: Unrelated: You may find [`std::lock_guard`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard) a worthwhile improvement to manually locking and unlocking a mutex. For example, it provides a satisfactory answer to the question, "What if an exception is thrown inside the protected region?"

Comment: Never. Ever. Use input data as a format string. Ever. It would be rather difficult to tell why your program crashes with this specific string without having a [mcve], but if you use `snprintf` the way you do, your program **will** crash sooner or later.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have to use the  format string as;

```
snprintf ( m_Text, 100, "%s", logMessage.c_str() );
```

more info can be found at

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/

i have tried your way ;

`snprintf ( m_Text, 100,logMessage.c_str() );`

if the `logmessage` contains a format string as such as `%s` it treats it as a format string and starts looking for the fourth argument of snprintf to place where the `%s`. since this is not provided, it causes a crash.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When it is not guaranteed that `logMessage.c_str()` doesn't contain any `%` control character this can produce undefined behavior which can lead to a crash when it is for example expecting a pointer to `char *` from `%s`.

`snprintf` used the way how you do it interprets `logMessage.c_str()` as the format string!

How ever, use `strcpy` but before set `m_Text` to `0x00` with `memset` or [std::memset](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memset).

For this you have to know the length/size if `m_Text`.

Using `snprintf( m_Text, 100, "%s", logMessage.c_str() )` would be also *safe* - supposing `m_Text` is big enough to hold 100 characters.

Try to avoid constant size parameters - in this case `100`. Once you change `m_Text` to a smaller size the program can also crash and you waste time to find the bug. `sizeof(m_Text)-1` is much more safer - as long `m_Text` is **NOT** a pointer! Then `sizeof` would return the size of a pointer instead of the size of the array.

So, when you want to use `snprintf` this would be the best way:

`snprintf( m_Text, sizeof(m_Text) - 1, "%s", logMessage.c_str() )`